# How to set Location in android app Google maps using appium

Tags: java, appium

I am testing google map for localization testing. I have to set location of except from my current location. But it is taking my current location.

**Sample Code:**

```
 Location location = new Location(77.59974003, 12.91024781, 909);
 driver.setLocation(location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the code which you have written for seting the location before the map is displayed.

```
Location location = new Location(77.59974003, 12.91024781, 909);
driver.setLocation(location);
```

This will set the driver location before the map is displayed on the screen.